# Cannot get required class to be found in composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

Here is the `composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "uci/uci-wp-webauth",
  "description": "Wordpress plugin for enabling WebAuth logging in for UCI users on a site-by-site basis.",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "minimimum-stability": "stable",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "includes/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "uci/uci-lib": "dev-master#9097b4f"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:username/uci-lib"
    }
  ]
}
```

The directory structure looks like:

```
UCI
    -WebAuth.php
```

And the WebAuth class is structured thus:

```
namespace UCI;

class WebAuth {}
```

The class/code that implements WebAuth:

```
namespace WebAuth;

use UCI\WebAuth;

class Handler
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();

        $this->webauth = new WebAuth();
```

For some reason PHP keep reporting back:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'UCI\WebAuth' not found
```

I've done this so many times before in setting up a composer project, but this one has really got me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have PSR-4 autoloader without specified namespace, so this is basically wrong:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "": "includes/"
  }
},
```

You must specify namespace that you want to map to a folder, however I'd rather replace the whole `psr-4` thing with simple `classmap`:

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap:: ["includes/"]
},
```

Comment: Thanks, for that tip. Unfortunately that has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: update your question with the code that tries to instantiate object of that class